# Postgresql check if an attribute is a substring of another attribute regardless of case

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

I wanna display the attributes login, name, gender, address, and joined from the table Player if the login is a substring of name (case insensitive)
For example,
if login is 'thom' and the name is 'Thomas' the query should return this tuple
if login is 'qw' and the name is 'Sarah' then the query shouldn't return this tuple

The query below is what I have so far and I've tried using LIKE and SIMILAR and substring but I can't figure it out

```
select login, name, gender, address, joined
from Player
where login ~* name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if login is 'thom' and the name is 'Thomas' the query should return this tuple

You seem to want the pattern match the other way around:

```
where name ~* login
```

You could also phrase this with `ilike`:

```
where name ilike '%' || login || '%'
```